# C# how to match generic types from different classes

Tags: c#, generics

On one hand I have a list of capabilities, for example:

```
public interface ICapability
{
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class RangeCapability<T> : ICapability
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Min { get; set; }
    public T Max { get; set; }
} 
public class SetCapability<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HashSet<T> Set { get; set; }
}
```

On the other hand I have a list of requirements

```
public interface IRequirement
{
    public string Name { get; }
}

public class Requirement<T> : IRequirement
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Both capability list may contain capabilities of different types T and requirement list may contain requirements of different types. The important thing is that if for a given name the underlying types match I should check if value is between min and max (for range class) or in a set like in the example below:

```
public class Entity
{
    List<ICapability> Capabilities { get; set; }

    public bool IsSatisfying(List<IRequirement> requirements)
    {
        foreach(var requirement in requirements)
        {
            var capability = Capabilities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == requirement .Name);
            //how to check if here if types match and if req. within range or in collection?
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure how to match generic types of two different classes and then do the check suitable for the apropriate implementation (is within range/is present in set). Can somebody point me in the right direction how could I make it work?

Comment: If the `Requirement`s were handling the `Satisfying` operation it would be easier to implement.

Comment: If you look at your `capability` (or one of your `requirements`) you'll see you can't; your interface doesn't include the generic or those fields.

Comment: Couldnt you put a method that returns bool in your interface(s)? That way you just iterate through `requirements` and call `PassesRequirements()` or something

Comment: You have to validate the types against something. Maybe an enum for both capabilities and requirements and then create a factory to determine the types and set the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.  Make the interfaces generic and also make the Entity class generic.

```
public interface INamed<T>
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public interface ICapability<T> : INamed<T>
{
}

public class RangeCapability<T> : ICapability<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Min { get; set; }
    public T Max { get; set; }
}
public class SetCapability<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public HashSet<T> Set { get; set; }
}

public interface IRequirement<T> : INamed<T>
{
}

public class Requirement<T> : IRequirement<T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Entity<T>
{
    List<ICapability<T>> Capabilities { get; set; }

    public bool IsSatisfying(List<IRequirement<T>> requirements)
    {
        foreach (var requirement in requirements)
        {
            var capability = Capabilities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == requirement.Name);
            //how to check if here if types match and if req. within range or in collection?
            if(capability is INamed<T>)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("types match");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not - capabilities from a single entity may have different types. For example: "height" between 10 and 20; "type" in ("round", "square").

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Okay, I refactored it a bit.  I extracted a common base interface for Name, then you can use the is operator to see if capability is compatible with the base interface.

Comment: There are two unknown types: 1) the actual `Capability` type and 2) the actual type of `T`.  Additionally, the way to compare the `Value` requires different compares (as shown). I don't think you can fix this by only adding another generic wrapper.